# Gradle Android plugin generate R files for different product flavors?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to merge my free app and paid app.  The productFlavors of Android's new build system seem to be a perfect fit for my problem.

I have the freeApp flavor working great, however when I build the paidApp flavor the R file that is being generated is in a package structure that is defined in the freeApp.

Here is a snippet from by gradle.build file:

```
productFlavors {
freeApp {
    versionCode 201308020
    versionName "2.0.13_free"
    packageName "com.flyingspheres.android"
}
paidApp {
    versionCode 201305110
    versionName "2.0.10_paid"
    packageName "com.flyingspheres.android.inventory"
}
```

I always believed the R file's location is defined by the package name in the manifest.  I verified that the manifest file is generating correctly.

The problem is that the R file for both flavors is located in the same location.  Gradle demands that a manifest lives within the main source tree so whatever version of the manifest I put in the main source tree that is where the R.java file will be generated at.

Assuming that I get the R files to generate in the correct location for each flavor; how are the import statements for the R file supposed to be managed so that each flavor references the correct R file?

Here is a screen shot of my project structure:

[image]

Each AndroidManifest.xml file is a full and complete manifest - according to the documentation the manifest in the main tree should completely overwrite the product flavor version.  Although, that is clearly not happening, because the activity that should be launched and the content providers aren't being overwritten.

Any insights to what I'm doing wrong would be most appreciated.  This has to be a very common situation that anyone overriding the packageName would run into.  I've been trying to figure it out for about a week now and can't seem to get there on my own.

Thanks,

-Aaron

Answer (score 10):

Under android's gradle plugin 0.7.3, the generated `R.java` file is ***only*** made for the **`src/main`'s package name**. It contains all the resources for the different flavors, it just puts them into one generated `R.java` file. I heard this from [an IO talk](http://youtu.be/LCJAgPkpmR0?t=23m33s).

What's your package name in the `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`? My guess is that it's `com.flyingspheres.android`

Try *importing* `R` in your classes which need to access resources programatically using your `src/main`'s package name.

E.g.

```
import com.flyingspheres.android.R;
```